# How can I pass an array( ) to another page in php?

Tags: php, arrays

So I wanted to pass an array to another page to use it later.

My code

```
<?php
code(1,2);
code(1,3);
function code($row,$col)
{
$z = rand(65,90);
$letter[$row][$col] = chr($z);//I want to pass this array.
}
?>
```

Now I want to access `$letter` in my another page.
Is it possible?

Comment: Store it in a session variable.

Comment: I tried `$_SESSION['$le'] = $letter ` but it's just storing the last evaluated value instead of whole array

Comment: You could also serialize the array, pass it as variable to the next page and unserialize it there.

Comment: Ok, I used `$_SESSION['le'][$row][$col] = $letter[$row][$col]; ` and it is working! Thanks @John Conde.

Comment: $_SESSION['$le'] = array_merge_recursive($_SESSION['$le'], $letter);